# Why do I get pinkish tint on some photos in DJI Mavic 2 Pro hyperlapse?

Tags: sensor, aerial-photography, tint

I tried to take a twilight hyperlapse with Mavic 2 Pro. However, there is a pinkish tint unevenly distributed randomly in the shots:

[image]

Needless to say, all images have the same settings (as part of being hyperlapse) and the end result has an awful "flickering" caused by this uneven tint when playing it as a video.

What is causing this and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1):

The images are DNG, so they undergo processing by Adobe. Most likely, there is an auto white balance set (or another colour setting), and it can easily be inconsistent, esp. in such difficult conditions.

Try to select all images and enforce a specific manual white balance and other settings, so that there were no 'auto' anywhere.

Comment: DNG is an open format that is for raw images. It's only specified by Adobe, not processed by it. Those DNGs are straight out of camera.

Comment: Still, DNG is raw, just openly specified. It _must_ be processed by whatever software is used to display it, Adobe suite in your case. (Except when showing a preview image embedded in DNG, in which case it was processed by the camera, often using some form of automatic settings).

Comment: I heavily doubt that it's the case, as the same artifacts are also present in the hyperlapse video from straight out of the drone.

Comment: Doubt what? That DNG has to be processed? This is undisputable. But of course the out-of-camera video will be very similar to default processing. Hyperlapse is shot as photos, and the camera estimates what is best (exposure, color balance, etc.) on a per-frame basis, unless you explicitly fix them. If it decided that this frame should have a different color, it will make it so in the photo as well as in the video. Arguably, it should fix parameters automatically based on the first frame, or change them gradually like with normal video, but DJI software has never been known for thorough design.

Comment: No I doubt the cause of the tint was the DNG conversion I mean as it's also apparent in video too. My settings are fully manual, so camera doesn't need to estimate anything other than white balance, which might be the case anyway. So you are saying that it's caused by color balancing?

Comment: @Can Poyrazoğlu, Do not asume for now, try this option first. After you have done everything to discard this it is the more feasable reason. If it is not, you have a problem with the camera and probably needs to be replaced...

Comment: @Rafael just realized the answer suggests manual WB too. didn't see that. will try.

Comment: As a rule, if you a going to post-process a video, manual white balance is a must.